# Why doesn't my prepare statement work?

Tags: php, html, mysql

For some reason, my prepare statement doesn't seem to return any rows or login, although I'm sure the password and username being entered is correct; when running the code without the prepare statement, the system logs in. Would anyone happen to know why my prepare statement isn't working, or if there is some other method I should use?

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Logged in</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        $user=$_GET["username"];
        $pass=$_GET["password"];


        $servername="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $dbName="db_artzytest";

        $conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

        if($conn->connect_error){
            echo $conn->connect_error;
            die("connection to server not found");
        }else{
            echo "connection established";
        }
        ///finds account with matching login info
        $sql="SELECT * FROM db_users WHERE username='{$user}' AND password='{$pass}' ";


        $sql="SELECT * FROM db_users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";


        try{
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
            $stmt->execute();
      }catch(Exception $e){
          die("prepare failed: " . $e);
      }
        echo 'here';
        //$result = $stmt->store_result();

        printf("Number of rows: %d. \n", $stmt->num_rows);

        //$result=$conn->query($sql);   
        echo 'here';
        if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                //only logs in if the account is activated
                if($row["isActivated"]==1){

                    $_SESSION["currentUser"]=$user;
                    $_SESSION["currentId"]=$row["id"];
                    $_SESSION["currentPass"]=$pass;

                    //header( 'Location: ../ProfilePage/profilePage.php' );
                    header( 'Location: ../Content/displayGroup.php?group=general' );
                }else{
                    $_SESSION["m_Login"]="Unverified Account. Check your email to verify.";
                    header('Location: Login.php');
                }
            }
            /*
            $sql=" SELECT * FROM table_images WHERE userid = {$_SESSION["currentId"]} ";

            $result=$conn->query($sql);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "<img style='height: 10vh; width: 10vw;' src='../../images/{$row["id"]}.jpg' />";
                    echo "{$row["imageName"]}</br>";
                }
            }
            */

        }else{
            $_SESSION["m_Login"]="password or username incorrect {$user} {$pass}"  . var_dump(mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt) );
            header('Location: Login.php');
            echo "no user found";
        }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the Java?

Comment: Basic debugging: Ensure `$_GET` is not meant to be `$_POST` and that data is being passed. Why do you define `$sql` and they immediately redefine it with question mark parameters? Always use `exit` with `header` to prevent errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing OO and procdeural so I'm going to assume that is what is causing your code not to execute as intended.

The documentation states:

> Procedural style only: A result set identifier returned by mysqli_query(), mysqli_store_result() or mysqli_use_result().

Change,

```
if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
```

To,

```
if($stmt->num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
```

That should fix the issue.

Comment: Oh, sorry my code is a little confusing, the $result variable was left over from the login code without the prepare statement. What should $result be set to now?